# FileOutputStream falha no context

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando reutilizar uma classe, que grava o arquivo no armazenamento interno.
Na primeira linha do `try`, o resultado é `null` (vindo da `activity`) e gera um erro.
Quando executo este codigo na `mainActivity`, ele funciona.

```
public class Modelo {
    private static Context context;

    public void saveDisciplina(String nome, Float p1, Float p2){
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
        String filename=" - "+nome;

        try {
            fileOutputStream=getContext().getApplicationContext()
                    .openFileOutput(filename,getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream.write(("Nome da disciplina: "+filename+"\n").getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(("Nota P1: "+p1+"\n").getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(("Nota P2: "+p2+"\n").getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }catch (IOException ex){

        }
        SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("com.fatec.karina.mygrades", 
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("nomed", String.valueOf(nomed));
        editor.putFloat("p1", p1);
        editor.putFloat("p2", p2);
        editor.commit();

    }

    public static Context getContext (){
        return context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Context estático é uma péssima ideia. Por que você não passa esse context no construtor?

Comment: Ou directamente no método.

Comment: OK, obrigado pela ajuda.
Coloquei diretamente no metodo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você fez assim ó:

```
// ...
try {
    // ...
    fileOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException ex){ //... }
```

para funcionar, voçê precisa fazer algo assim ó:

```
// ...
PrintWriter writer = null;
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos)));
    writer.println(("Nome da disciplina: "+filename+"\n").getBytes());
    // ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (null != writer) {
        writer.close();
    }
}
// ...
```

**Nota:** esse é um exemplo o mais básico possível, voce pode moldar a partir dele para as tuas necessidades, aqui comigo funcionou!

Espero que ajude!!!

Comment: criei um construtor com o context.
eo restante class
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream)));
            writer.println(("Nome da disciplina: " + filename + "\n").getBytes());
}catch (IOException ex){
      SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("com.fatec.karina.mygrades",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor= preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("nomed", String.valueOf(filename));

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void saveDisciplina(String nome, Float p1, Float p2, Context context){
     // context recebendo no parametro do método ou no construtor
     // método
}
```

Comment: Colocando no método, eu ja havia tentando, mas fiquei em dúvida na hora de trazer o parâmetro do context.